# Script lock for different users google app maker

Tags: google-apps-script

i'm struggling with problem of running script by 2 or more users in the same time. Script adds data to spreadsheet and creates folders in google drive.
I've tried using Lockservice, but it didn't work. And I've made my own 'Lock' which change value in sheet and when this Busy status is true script won't run, but it changes too slow.

```
function thisRunsClient(){
    var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
    if(lock.hasLock()){return 'END')};
    else{
    lock.tryLock(10000)};
   //rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I use is

```
var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
    try {
        lock.waitLock(30000); // wait 30 seconds for others' use of the code section and lock to stop and then proceed
    } catch (e) {
        Logger.log('Could not obtain copy lock after 20 seconds.');
        return;
    }
//REST OF CODE
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the haslock there, it looks to me like if you get the lock you immediately end the function, which doesn't seem like what you want to do.

Comment: With haslock i only want to check is this script locked and if it's locked return 'END'. I used yours solution but still i have nothing in my logs.

Comment: Mine will only log if it fails to get the lock, add Logger.log ("What about this"); below the rest of code flag and try it.

Comment: Hey @Kosaaaaa does the provided answer work for you?

Comment: great! please mark my solution as correct when you get the chance